# Escape hyphen in fields for logstash

Tags: json, parsing, escaping, logstash

I have a problem with logstash parsing, I need to extract a field separated by hyphen:

```
if "[payload][text][code][session-id]" {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "session-id" => "%{[payload][text][code][session-id]}" }
  }
}
```

the conditional is working because the quotes, but when I run the filter, it returns:

```
t session-id: %{[payload][text][code][session-id]}
```

and what I expect is:

```
t session-id: HK5wfPQgzkKHmgzVF
```

how I can scape the hypens in the payload field?

Comment: I didn't reproduce the issue. Are you sure there's not a typo somewhere?

Comment: I double check it, no typo, I'm using logstash 7.1

Comment: I didn't reproduce with 6.4 and 7.1 (I had tried with 6.4 first and installed 7.1 after your comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong, putting the field name between double quotes will make it a string and it will always be true, so your `mutate` filter will always run and add the field `session-id` with the content of the field `[payload][text][code][session-id]`, if the field does not exist, the string `%{[payload][text][code][session-id]}` will be added into `session-id` as the value of the field.

Your conditional should be `if [payload][text][code][session-id]` without double quotes.

You can reproduce this behavior with the following test pipeline

```
input {
    generator {
        message => "HK5wfPQgzkKHmgzVF"
        count => 1
    }
}
filter {
    dissect {
        mapping => {
            "message" => "%{[payload][text][code][session-id]}"
        }
    }
    if "[payload][text][code][session-id]" {
        mutate {
            add_field => { "session-id" => "%{[payload][text][code][session-id]}"}
        }
    }
}
output {
    stdout { }
}
```

Running this pipeline will give you the field `session-id` with the value `HK5wfPQgzkKHmgzVF` because the field `[payload][text][code][session-id]` exists and your conditional is always true, if you change the name of the field to `[payload][text][code][session-id-test]` in the `dissect` block and run the pipeline again, the value of `session-id` will now be `%{[payload][text][code][session-id]}`.

Remove the double quotes from the conditional and it will only be true if the field `[payload][text][code][session-id]` really exists.

Comment: thanks for the comment, part of the problem was the double quotes, the other part was `[[payload]]`was from grok, and I need it run the json filter first.